# Can someone explain this code using the .bind() function to me?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I encountered this snippet (event handling) from the jQuery source code:

```
var events = ['click', 'focus', 'blur', …];
jQuery.each(event,function(i,name){
    jQuery.prototype[name] = function(fn){
        return this.bind(name,fn);
    };
});
```

Can someone explain this to me? How does the `this.bind(name,fn);` work the same as `element.addEventListener('event','callback()')`?

I know the basics of JavaScript, but I do not know the more advanced parts of JavaScript. Since I taught myself, there are many holes in my JavaScript knowledge. If anyone knows of a good source I could learn more advanced JavaScript from I would like to hear that too.

Comment: have you tried to search it on Internet?? If not then just go through this link. http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: It iterates over the events, setting them as properties of `jQuery` with prototype, and then sets the new property to reference a function wrapping the native javascript `bind` method

Comment: @RonakBhatt it's not jquery's .bind. That's the wrong link

Comment: See [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) which is part of ES5 (and shim-able in older browsers; I use [es5-shim.js](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim)).

Comment: @Fresheyeball- then whats the correct link???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's quite simple we have all events in an array `[click, focus ...]` easily we apply a foreach on that array and next part of code assign a function to jQuery prototype `$.fn.click()` which will become `$('#me').click()`, and finally this `click();` function calls `$.fn.bind();` which will call `addEventListener()` later, that's it.

if you still wondering where is `addEventListener()` read [about](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) `bind()` in jQuery.